# Run asynchronous coroutines as celery tasks

Tags: python, async-await, celery, tornado, python-asyncio

I want to have an ability to use asynchronous code in my celery tasks. It's applicable both for asyncio or tornado. I found out, that i can do something like this

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

from celery._state import _task_stack

from . import celery


class AsyncTask(celery.Task):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _task_stack.push(self)
        self.push_request(args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        try:
            IOLoop.current().run_sync(lambda: self.run(*args, **kwargs))
        finally:
            self.pop_request()
            _task_stack.pop()
```

And then use it like this

```
from .celery import celery
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

@celery.task(base=AsyncTask)
async def test_async_celery_task(x, y):
    result = await AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(request='https://google.com.ua')
    print('Async IS OKAY: {}'.format(result))
```

Alternatively i can use `run_sync` directly in tasks, which is not preferable

I wonder if it's OK to do the above or i should start event loop in worker and start my tasks via `add_future`. Is there any other people, who did something similar? Can i hope for some performance enhancement?

I need this, because i need an ability to use asynchronous code from other parts of the project, like database calls ets

Answer (score 0):

It's not the correct use of ioloop that makes this complex, but making Celery know that it can and should use async tasks. Celery operates with Pools, where it can schedule your jobs. Pools can be threaded, can be multiprocessed, Celery knows (via configuration) that it has X processes, Y threads, Z workers, how many of them have jobs or free. But ATM, Celery technically is able to receive and run coroutines, but out the box is unable to count them to track how many of them have jobs or free. If you'd like to take a look how might it look like - there is [a development code of future Celery's Asyncpool](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/5.0-devel/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py).